# Problem with inscribed and circumscribed circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I have a geometry problem I am struggling with:

Circle $I$ is inscribed in $\triangle FGH$ and circle $O$ is circumscribed about $\triangle FGH$. $\overrightarrow{FI}$ intersects circle $O$ in a point $K$. Discover and prove a relationship between $\overline{KG}$, $\overline{KH}$, and $\overline{KI}$.

My sense is that $\overline{KG}\cong\overline{KH}\cong\overline{KI}$. However, I do not know how to prove this using any easy methods. My first sense was to draw a diagram, but given that $I$ is located inside the circle and I do not know anything about the angles and arcs of the circle, I have no clue where to begin. Some help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Hint: There's an important fact about ray $\overrightarrow{FI}$.

Comment: I see! It bisects angle $GFH$, so angles $GFI$ and $IFH$ are congruent. This means angles $GHK$ and $HGK$ are congruent, since they intercept the same arc as the $GFI$ and $IFH$ respectively, so $KG=KH$. However, I do not know how to apply a similar argument to $KI$, since at least $G$ and $H$ are on a circle.

Comment: @AadiRane: You're getting there. ... Now, consider $\angle KGI$ and $\angle KIG$. Think of the latter as an external angle of $\triangle IFG$.

Comment: I think I got it now. $m\angle KIG=m\angle GFI+m\angle FGI$ by the Exterior Triangle Theorem. But $m\angle FGI=m\angle HGI$, since $\overrightarrow{GI}$ bisects $\angle FGH$. Also, $m\angle GFI=m\angle KGH$, since they are two inscribed angles intercepting the same arc. Also $m\angle KGI=m\angle KGH+m\angle HGI$ by angle addition. Thus $m\angle KGI=m\angle KIG$, so by the Isosceles Triangle Theorem, $KG=KI$. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AadiRane: That's it! ... Now, put your work into an answer so that we can upvote your success (and to remove your question from the Unanswered queue). Also, be sure to accept your answer when you can.